# What is the exact python3 equivalent of python2's unicode(v, errors='ignore')?

Tags: python-3.x, string, python-2.7, python-unicode

What is the exact python3 equivalent of python2's `unicode(v, errors='ignore')` ?

Note that:

1. `v` is any string (e.g. `six.string_types`)
2. `errors='ignore'` is crucial

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `v` is already part of `six.string_types`, the only option for `v` is to be a `str`. Python 3 `str` is the equivalent of Python 2 `unicode`, so this conversion is redundant as you're just going to be converting `str` to `str`.

If you wanted to convert `bytes` (which is **not** part of `six.string_types`) to `str`, then you want `b.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")`, or just `str(b, errors = "ignore")`.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my understanding in your para 2 - works!